# Where to find the definition of a given beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes

I want to modify a detail in the header/footer lines of a beamer theme that I am using (for instance *Antibes*). Where can I find the corresponding definition file, to copy the existing definition of the header-footer lines?

Comment: You can always look into CTAN for latex code: A google search with "ctan antibes" gives this:
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antibes uses the tree outer theme. You can find the definition of its headline in [`beamerouterthemetree.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemetree.sty):

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{tree theme}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
      \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
          \hskip2pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
          \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
      \else%  
        \hskip6pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
      \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
          \hskip9.4pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
          \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
      \else%  
        \hskip12pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

*(it does not have a footline)*

Comment: If I want to modify this, can I edit it inside my .tex file, or should I make a new beamer theme containing my edits? (If needed, I can turn this comment into a new question.)

Comment: @Karlo You can do it within your tex file after loading your theme, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404219/36296